# dynamics names of leaflet layers in a angularjs foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I define a marker and his layer in a angularjs foreach. I try to attach the creation of a onclick event for the layer.

The marker is always named 'markersLayer_' + the id:

```
// Layer Marker Loop Adding
angular.forEach($scope.data.markers, function(item) {

    // define variables
    var name = 'markersLayer_' + item.id;
    itemLayer = name;

    // leaflet : creating the marker and then add it to a new layer
    name = new L.LayerGroup();
    L.marker([item.geolocalisation.lat, item.geolocalisation.long], {icon: new NewIcon}).addTo(name);
    map.addLayer(name);

    console.log(itemLayer);
```

But there is a problem : layers are not defined. Markers are correctly added but only at map and not at each layer, it's a problem of how i declared and named variables ?

After this, i would like to attach a onclick event on each layer, but if i do it like `itemLayer.on('click', function (e) {` it can't working because layer is not defined.

Comment: Thats obvious behaviour, itemLayer is not an element.

Comment: how to attach click event to a layer ? with geojson there is onEachFeature, but with not geojson ?

Comment: You can try `google.maps.event.addListener(name, 'click', function (e) { //your code here});` inside your each link before `map.addLayer(name);`